# Exporting Chaco plots to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, svg, eps, chaco

I want to save some Chaco plots to PDF (or another vector format such as EPS or SVG). I have already discovered [`PdfPlotGraphicsContext`](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ETS3_API/enthought.chaco.pdf_graphics_context.PdfPlotGraphicsContext.html), but this suffers from two problems:

- the PDF's page size is not adjusted to the size of the plot (requires a cropping post-processing step)
- it doesn't seem to support transparency

Can these issues be worked around somehow, or is there an alternative way of exporting plots in a vector format?